# GEE - Get date of ImageCollection mosaic

Tags: google-earth-engine, labeling, mosaic, date

I have created mosaics by date from an ImageCollection and now want to label each mosaic with its corresponding date. This is my function to label the ImageCollection:

```
var date_label_pos = ee.Geometry.Point([32.55, -15.42]);
var scale = 200;

function annotate(collection) {
  return collection.map(function(img) {
    // define text properties
    var props = {
      fontFamily: 'Calibri', 
      fontStyle: 'bold', 
      textColor: '1D4180', 
      outlineColor: 'ffffff', 
      outlineWidth: 2.5, 
      outlineOpacity: 0.6
    };
    var center = ee.List(date_label_pos.coordinates());
    var pos = translate(center, 0, 0);
    var s = ee.String(' DATE SHOULD BE HERE!');
    var date_label = Text.draw(s, pos, scale * 1.5, props);
    // merge results
    var image = img.visualize({forceRgbOutput: true, min: 500, max: 1800, bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2']});
    return ee.ImageCollection([image, date_label]).mosaic(); 
  });
}
```

The full code is [HERE](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users/bernerthendrik/testing:cahora_mosaic_timelapse). What I'm missing is the part where I can extract the date from the image mosaic. `img.date()` does not work.

---

To provide a little bit more info: I needed to set a new property `date` to the mosaics, which I can see when I print the ImageCollection to the console. I can also access that date outside of the `annotate` function using:

```
print(ee.Image(mosaics.toList(mosaics.size()).get(0)).get('date'));
```

where `mosaics` is my ImageCollection. But within the function, it seems that `img` is something different and I can't figure out what it is and how I can access the `date` property I set.

Comment: You should post or share the full code example using the "Get Link (shareable snapshot)" link, not the "Copy script Path" link. Looking at the small piece of code in your question body, it is difficult to evaluate what you are trying to do..  especially the part where you are doing `ee.ImageCollection([image, date_label]).mosaic` -- that doesn't seem to make sense

Comment: I fear I lost access to the full script (probably due to the exact mistake you pointed out), so although I'd love see this solved, I cannot provide any further information.

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked a long time ago, but nevertheless, here is the answer. The main questions is related to the following line:

```js
var s = ee.String(' DATE SHOULD BE HERE!');
```

The `img.date()` can't be passed here as an argument because it is of an `ee.Date()` type, to turn it into a string you need to use `ee.Date.format()`, e.g., `img.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm')`. which would return a string and that can be passed as an argument to the `draw()` function to turn that string into an image.

If you'd like to use something like `mosaics.first().date()` after you apply the `annotate()` function, you need to propagate the `system:time_start` property to the resulting images, you can do it by making use of `copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start'])` function. The `date()` function is just a [helper function](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-date) passing that property to the `ee.Date()`.

Furthermore, the code miscalculates the text position. It's always a constant value based on the `date_label_pos`. I've replaced it with the image centroid and added missing pieces to generate a working example: https://code.earthengine.google.com/4cb8c1c370d4ecbe62fc728391877275. Notice that the code copies the `system:time_start` property from the original image to ensure that the `date()` still works. The final code adds image times as annotations.

[image: output]